# EXPKEYSIG 68818C72E52529D4 MongoDB 4.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I was wondering if anyone can help figuring out about how to deal with the issue of expired key.

Basically, I was re-installing `mongodb` which I have done successfully before, but now that the key expired in 2023-04-17 I can't do it any more.

```
sudo apt-key list
...
pub   rsa4096 2018-04-18 [SC] [expired: 2023-04-17]
      9DA3 1620 334B D75D 9DCB  49F3 6881 8C72 E525 29D4
uid           [ expired] MongoDB 4.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/certbot_ubuntu_certbot.gpg
...
```

What I did was

```
sudo apt-key del 68818C72E52529D4
...
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 68818C72E52529D4
...
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
...
Err:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 68818C72E52529D4 MongoDB 4.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
Hit:20 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 Release
Ign:18 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
...
```

Thank you in advance,
Vlad

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-db-4-0-gpg-key-expired-for-ubuntu-18-04/230854